# Why is JetBlue's IATA code B6?

Tags: airline-operations, iata

I understand why JetBlue's IATA code isn't JB since that belongs to a pre-existing helijet service in Canada, but why is it B6?

Is there some history behind the B6 moniker?

Comment: I've pinged JetBlue via Twitter, hopefully they have an answer.

Comment: @SargunDhillon Seems, they didn't! :>

Comment: @trejder Look at Sargun's comment on RedGrittyBrick's answer.

Comment: Software devs know - same reason we have k8s and i18n I suspect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know, but ...

If you look at the [IATA application form](http://www.iata.org/services/Documents/codes-designator-form.pdf) you will see there is nowhere for the airline to indicate the code it would like to receive.

I imagine many new airlines might indicate a preference in an accompanying letter (e.g. they would like a code starting with a specific letter)

If you look at the allocated codes you can see that, initially, some attempt was made by IATA to make the two-character codes mnemonic

```
AA = American Airlines
BA = British Airways
etc
```

However if JB was already allocated, it is reasonable that the IATA
staff would look for an available code starting with either J or B.
Since the Blue of JetBlue is more distinguishing than the Jet part of the name, the IATA employee may have started with B and noticed that the following were already [allocated](http://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/code-search.aspx)

```
B1 Bravo Passenger Solution Pte., Ltd. 
B2 Belavia 
B3 Bhutan Airlines dba Tashi Air Pvt L 
B4 ZanAir Limited 
B5 East African Safari Air Express Ltd.
```

(note I have not checked dates these codes were allocated but the hypothesis seems plausible to me)

The last two are puzzling but perhaps they changed their names (perhaps as part of a takeover, merger or split). Airline codes do get reused. For example, B5 was used by FlightLine before it went out of business.

Then B6 would be the next available code.

Comment: I think you're right about it just being next in line. If you look at the years they were founded they go in sequence. I don't think the B has any significance since the airline was having [major trouble coming up with a name](http://www.travelandleisure.com/articles/jetblue-airlines-its-all-in-a-name) and went through several, so they just got the next in sequence. If they had a name from the start they might have been able to get something specific but they apparently came up with jetblue at the last moment.

Comment: This seems correct: http://i.imgur.com/qcos5eW.png. The IATA naming process seems somewhat opaque.

Comment: *VERY* interesting. I always wondered why the Concord was SpeedBird, now it seems IATA staff are a bit arbitrary and capricious !!!

Comment: @jzumwalt Speedbird is the British Airways callsign, not limited to Concorde. It's Speedbird for historic reasons (the callsign of the BOAC, which was established before the IATA existed).